# Injecting Request object into controller's constructor, on an API route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

**Problem**

It seems like my API-handling controller cannot process an injected `Request` object. Details below.

I have a route in my **api.php** routes file:

```
Route::namespace('Mailing')->prefix('mailing/webhook')->group(function () {

    Route::post('open', 'WebhookController@getOpened');

});
```

In the **WebhookController.php**, there's a constructor with the injected `Request` object:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


public function __construct(Request $request) {

    // Log it in the database   
    Logger::info('constructor called...');

    // Filter the input in the injected Request
    $this->input = $this->getFilteredInput($request);
}
```

Now, when I deploy this code to the server and make the API call against my endpoint, the log message at the beginning of the `__construct()` method is not even fired. I also get no data stored in the database (which should happen if the webhook is correctly processed).

**What I tested**

However, when I create a dummy route in **web.php** routes file:

```
Route::post('open', 'WebhookController@getOpened');
```

and then create a form and make a `POST` call to the `getOpened()` method - all works as expected: I have the `Request` injected and can manipulate it.

I checked that:

- The API endpoint is correct and available
- There are no obsolete `use` statements at the top of the
  `WebhookController`

**Questions**

Why does the **api.php** route fail on me? Doesn't [Laravel's dependency injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers) work for API-handling controllers?

Comment: Not sure and curious: can you even use Route::namespace('Mailing'), is that valid? Can't find anything about it. Mostly namespace is used within ->group([]).

Comment: Sure you [can](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-namespaces) do it ;)